# Linear regression with LOOCV split in R returns Error

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, cross-validation

I tried to fit a linear model using Leave one out cross-validation split.

I used this [**DATASET**](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/), the dataset has 517 rows and 13 columns (two of them are categorical variables). The dependent variable is "area".

I would like to build a model with and without the categorical variables. Then is to calculate the coefficients mean. When I removed the categorical variables, the code runs fine, but when I keep them I got the following error ***" Error in estcoef[i, ] <- coef(model1) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"***

My code is as follows

```
wdbc<- read.csv("forestfires.csv") ## upload the dataset
wdbc<-wdbc[-(3:4)] ## If I want to build the model without the catogrical variables
#####################################

fitted_value <- rep(0,nrow(wdbc))
estcoef<-matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc),ncol=ncol(wdbc)) #estimation coefficients

# LOOCV split leave one out cross validation 
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc)){
  validation<-wdbc[i,]
  training<-wdbc[-i,]
  model1<-lm(area ~ ., data = training)
  fitted_value[i] <- predict(model1, newdata = validation) 
  estcoef[i,]<-coef(model1) 
}

meancoef<-colMeans(estcoef) #coefficent means
```

Could anyone help me with this problem, please?

I am happy to provide any other additional information.

***UPDATED***

I included the first 10 rows of my data

```
  X Y month day FFMC   DMC    DC  ISI temp RH wind rain area
1  7 5   mar fri 86.2  26.2  94.3  5.1  8.2 51  6.7  0.0    0
2  7 4   oct tue 90.6  35.4 669.1  6.7 18.0 33  0.9  0.0    0
3  7 4   oct sat 90.6  43.7 686.9  6.7 14.6 33  1.3  0.0    0
4  8 6   mar fri 91.7  33.3  77.5  9.0  8.3 97  4.0  0.2    0
5  8 6   mar sun 89.3  51.3 102.2  9.6 11.4 99  1.8  0.0    0
6  8 6   aug sun 92.3  85.3 488.0 14.7 22.2 29  5.4  0.0    0
7  8 6   aug mon 92.3  88.9 495.6  8.5 24.1 27  3.1  0.0    0
8  8 6   aug mon 91.5 145.4 608.2 10.7  8.0 86  2.2  0.0    0
9  8 6   sep tue 91.0 129.5 692.6  7.0 13.1 63  5.4  0.0    0
10 7 5   sep sat 92.5  88.0 698.6  7.1 22.8 40  4.0  0.0    0
```

***I also included the last 10 rows which show that we have only one row with month= Nov(last row), that return errors even with the provided answer.***

```
> tail(wdbc,10)
    X Y month day FFMC   DMC    DC  ISI temp RH wind rain  area
508 2 4   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 25.9 41  3.6  0.0  0.00
509 1 2   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 25.9 41  3.6  0.0  0.00
510 5 4   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 21.1 71  7.6  1.4  2.17
511 6 5   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 18.2 62  5.4  0.0  0.43
512 8 6   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 27.8 35  2.7  0.0  0.00
513 4 3   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 27.8 32  2.7  0.0  6.44
514 2 4   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 21.9 71  5.8  0.0 54.29
515 7 4   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 21.2 70  6.7  0.0 11.16
516 1 4   aug sat 94.4 146.0 614.7 11.3 25.6 42  4.0  0.0  0.00
517 6 3   nov tue 79.5   3.0 106.7  1.1 11.8 31  4.5  0.0  0.00
```

Comment: Have you looked at `coef(model1)` and `length(coef(model1))`? You seem to be assuming that the number of coefficients is the same as the number of columns, and that is not the case. Since I don't have your data, I can't check what's different. But `coef(model1)` should be a nicely named vector which would shed light on the problem...

Comment: If one of the regressors is categorical with `n` levels you might have more coefficients, `n - 1` for this variable alone. Plus the other regressors.

Comment: @Gregor, I provided the link of the data in the question.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, so what should I do to make my code works as without categorical variables.

Comment: Done, see my answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas , see my comment and update, please.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can easily be solved if instead of creating a matrix to store the coefficients, they are stored in a `list`. Like this there will be no items to replace, all will be taken care of later.

In the code that follows I use built in data set `iris`, changing the name of the response to `area`.

```
wdbc <- iris
names(wdbc)[1] <- "area"

fitted_value <- rep(0, nrow(wdbc))
estcoef <- vector("list", length = nrow(wdbc))

# LOOCV split leave one out cross validation 
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc)){
  validation <- wdbc[i,]
  training <- wdbc[-i, ]
  model1 <- lm(area ~ ., data = training)
  fitted_value[i] <- predict(model1, newdata = validation) 
  estcoef[[i]] <- coef(model1) 
}

estcoef <- do.call(rbind, estcoef)
meancoef <- colMeans(estcoef) # coefficent means
```

**Edit.**

The Op complains about an error:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
>   factor month has new level nov

This is because the data set only has one row with `month == "nov"` so when fitting the model with that one row left out, the `validation` data set has a value in the `month` column that is not present in the `training` data set and `predict` does not know what to do with it.

The solution is to use `tryCatch` to trap the error and let the code continue running. The function below is the repetition of the code above, with a call to `tryCatch`. It returns the coefficients means and the fitted values. When `predict` gives an error the returned value is `NaN`. Change this at will.

```
fitModelLOOCV <- function(DF){

  fitted_value <- rep(0, nrow(DF))
  estcoef <- vector("list", length = nrow(DF))

  # LOOCV split leave one out cross validation 
  for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
    validation <- DF[i,]
    training <- DF[-i, ]
    model1 <- lm(area ~ ., data = training)
    fitted_value[i] <- tryCatch(predict(model1, newdata = validation),
                                error = function(e) {print(e); NaN})
    estcoef[[i]] <- coef(model1) 
  }

  estcoef <- do.call(rbind, estcoef)
  meancoef <- colMeans(estcoef) # coefficent means
  list(meancoef = meancoef, fitted = fitted_value)
}

fitModelLOOCV(wdbc)
```

An alternative is to remove the problem value before running the function. (Maybe just one data point is not that important.)

```
wdbc2 <- wdbc[-which(wdbc$month == "nov"), ]
fitModelLOOCV(wdbc2)
```

Comment: thanks, but when I run the code on my data I got 'Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor month has new level nov'

Comment: @jeza The error is in the call to `predict`. This is because there is only one row with `month == "nov"`. So when it was renoved from the training data the fitted model has no `nov`. Then you try to predict with a new level and `predict` does not know what to do with that value.

Comment: @jeza See the edit. Maybe the added code solves the problem.

Comment: I see. ok is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: thank you so much I will consider this as a solution unless we got someone else answer.